# Child component template contents does not show up when hosted in the parent component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue3 with options api as shown in the code posted below. I have a child component and it is hosted in the parent component as shown below.

The problem is, at run time, despite the `showNotificationsWindowsContainer` is set to `true`, the `NotificationsWindowsContainer.vue` does not show up.
To solve this issue, I enclosed the `<NotificationsWindowsContainer>` in the parent component within a `<div>` with an `id`, then, at runtime, the `NotificationsWindowsContainer.vue` showed up.
But I do not want to wrap the `<NotificationsWindowsContainer>` in the parent component around a `<div>`

I want the parent component to host the child component as in the way shown in my code below.

My question is, why the code of parent component shown below can not show the contents of `<NotificationsWindowsContainer>`

**child component**

```
<template>
    <div id="idDivNotificationsWindowsContainer" v-show="showNotificationsWindowsContainer">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'NotificationsWindowsContainer',
    data() {
        return {
        };
    },
    components: {},
    props: {
        showNotificationsWindowsContainer: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
    },
    computed: {},
    methods: {},
};
</script>

<style>
    @import '../../../map/assets/css/NDVIComparisonTab/Notifications/NotificationsWindowsContainer.css';
</style>
```

**parent component**:

```
<template>
    <NotificationsWindowsContainer
        v-bind:showNotificationsWindowsContainer="showNotificationsWindowsContainer"
    ></NotificationsWindowsContainer>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    name: 'NDVIComparisonGUI',
    data() {
        return {
            showNotificationsWindowsContainer: true,
....
....
....
```

**css of the child component**:

```
#idDivNotificationsWindowsContainer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

mentioned in the question

Comment: what's the value of `showNotificationsWindowsContainer` in the parent?

Comment: @JaromandaX it is set to true as well

Comment: then there is no reason, given only the code you've shown, that you shouldn't see a chartreuse 500x500 pixel square on your page

Comment: Have you simply tried `v-show="true"` just to test? Or alternatively use `v-if="true"` but of course replace `true` with `showNotificationsWindowsContainer` after you tested that it works. What will also help you a lot is using [Vue Developer Tools for Chrome](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd). It will show you the internal state of Vue objects.

Comment: @PeterPointer i set v-show to true, but still it does not show up

Comment: In that case do you have any errors in the browser console? Does it work with a normal HTML tag instead of a component?

Comment: @PeterPointer OP claims it works if he wraps `NotificationsWindowsContainer` in a `div`

Comment: I see you've tagged this both vue2 AND vue3 - pick one

Comment: @PeterPointer i have no errors in devtools console.

Comment: Okay good but do you see anything wrong in the Vue dev tools? It will show you the exact state of the Vue components. Maybe the `NotificationsWindowsContainer` is being weird. Also you can create a runnable example with the `<>` button. Add vue using the select fields on the left.

Comment: @PeterPointer i check vue-tools and surprisingly, the child component  `<NotificationsWindowsContainer>` is never listed. while i can see all the other components

Comment: That seems weird, indeed. Have you tried just moving the `v-show`  out of the child component and just have the parent have the `v-show` or `v-if`? It is usually not necessary to pass such a show/hide flag to a child component since you can just control that on the parent directly with `v-if` and `v-show` directly.

Answer (score 1):

the error was in the way the component `NotificationsWindowsContainer` is imported.

instead of:

```
import { NotificationsWindowsContainer}  from 
'../NDVIComparisonTab/Notifications/NotificationsWindowsContainer.vue';
```

i replaced it with :

```
 import NotificationsWindowsContainer from 
 '../NDVIComparisonTab/Notifications/NotificationsWindowsContainer.vue';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug in Vue3 version 3.4.16

https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/10294

Update the npm package can resolve the problem.